# JSONArray and ArrayList getting replaced for every value insertion

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, arraylist

JSONArray getting replaced for every value insertion

In this below output I am getting replaced by old jArrayFacebookData.

or I need those json data should be add to string

dbchooseuserid,dbchoosebookid,dbchoosechapterid,dbchoosequestionid, Type,dbchooseoptionidthose valus are from db with those values I need to make json string

I need output like this

```
string h =[{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"hint","question_id":"1","notes":",,Gg,,,,"},{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"choose","question_id":"1","option_id":"1"}]
```

This is my code

```
JSONArray jArrayFacebookData = new JSONArray();
         JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();


ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<String>();
if(TypeHint.equals("hint"))
         {
  try {
                        jObjectData.put("user_id", dbhintuserid);
                        jObjectData.put("book_id", dbhintbookid);
                        jObjectData.put("chapter_id", dbhintchapterid);
                        jObjectData.put("question_type", TypeHint);
                        jObjectData.put("question_id", dbhintquestionid);
                        jObjectData.put("notes", dbhintnotes);

                        jArrayFacebookData.put(jObjectData);
                        Log.i("tag555", ""+jArrayFacebookData.toString());
 a.add(jObjectData.toString());
        Log.i("tag5", ""+a);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}

if(Type.equals("choose"))
         {
  try {
                        jObjectData.put("user_id", dbchooseuserid);
                        jObjectData.put("book_id", dbchoosebookid);
                        jObjectData.put("chapter_id", dbchoosechapterid);
                        jObjectData.put("question_type", Type);
                        jObjectData.put("question_id", dbchoosequestionid);
                        jObjectData.put("option_id", dbchooseoptionid);

                        jArrayFacebookData.put(jObjectData);
                        Log.i("tag555", ""+jArrayFacebookData.toString());
 a.add(jObjectData.toString());
        Log.i("tag5", ""+a);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
```

Output I am getting is

```
[{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"choose","question_id":"1","option_id":"1"}]
```

But I need output like this

```
[{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"hint","question_id":"1","notes":",,Gg,,,,"}{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"choose","question_id":"1","option_id":"1"}]
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on javascript but i noticed a couple of things. Firstly you replace the "question_type" with either "TypeHint" or "Type". If you want the value to be "notes" you should probably use "TypeHint". Secondly it looks like some kind of error occurs when setting the "notes" object. You could try using "console.error(e);" instead of printing the stacktrace to see more details on the JSON exception

Comment: i need output like this string h =[{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"hint","question_id":"1","notes":",,Gg,,,,"},{"user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"choose","question_id":"1","option_id":"1"}]

Comment: can you post the complete code from this code it look like you have issue in calling class/method, if you carefully check your array and list will gets initialised on every call so you won't get desire result unless you initialised them out side and just add item here.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `JSONObject` after every if condition and then try.

```
 if(TypeHint.equals("hint")){
     JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();
      ......


   if(Type.equals("choose")){
    JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();
    ....
```

Comment: can you paste here full package details of `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`?

Comment: full pakage means? i am using ksoap

Comment: Package name of JSONObject, like `net.sf.json.JSONObject`  I mean which APIs you are using for JSONObject and JSONArray.

Comment: dbchooseuserid,dbchoosebookid,dbchoosechapterid,dbchoosequestionid, Type,dbchooseoptionidthose valus are from db with those valus i need to make json string